# TensorFlow: cross-compile XLA to Android

Tags: android, c++, tensorflow, xla

I am trying to cross-compile a small project to android via XLA.
Compiling it for PC works fine, but for the android I get a linking error:

```
error: undefined reference to '__multi3'
```

I am currently on TensorFlow commit: 85827b2356d33e54d2e1413fc2005b08cde72f8  (Thu Apr 27 17:51:34 2017)
But I have tried several other version along with the major releases 1.0.1 and 1.1.0.

In the root of TensorFlow I change WORKFLOW and BUILD file as such

## WORKSPACE

```
android_ndk_repository(
   name="androidndk",
   path="/home/john/Android/android-ndk-r12b",
   api_level=14)
```

## BUILD

```
load("//tensorflow/compiler/aot:tfcompile.bzl", "tf_library")

tf_library(
    name = "mymodel",
    cpp_class = "mynamespace::mymodel",
    graph = "mymodel.pb",
    config = "mymodel.config.pbtxt",
)


cc_binary(
    name = "myproject",
    srcs = [
        "myproject.cpp"
    ],
    deps = [
        ":mymodel",
        "//third_party/eigen3",
    ],
    linkopts = [
        "-llog",
        "-lm",
    ],
)
```

My mimimal project

## myproject.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#define EIGEN_USE_THREADS
#define EIGEN_USE_CUSTOM_THREAD_POOL

#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include "third_party/eigen3/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/Tensor"
#include "mymodel.h"


int main()  {
  Eigen::ThreadPool tp(2);
  Eigen::ThreadPoolDevice device(&tp, tp.NumThreads());

  mynamespace::mymodel instance;
  instance.set_thread_pool(&device);

  // Just testing
  instance.Run();
}
```

I build using the following command

```
bazel build :myproject \
 --crosstool_top=//external:android/crosstool \
 --cpu=armeabi-v7a \
 --host_crosstool_top=@bazel_tools//tools/cpp:toolchain \
 --copt="-std=c++11" \
 --copt="-mfpu=neon" \
 --verbose_failures
```

## Output from build

```
ERROR: /home/john/build/tensorflow/BUILD:13:1: Linking of rule '//:myproject' failed: arm-linux-androideabi-gcc failed: error executing command 
  (cd /home/john/.cache/bazel/_bazel_john/32217266591f56f6caea7dc2786fea1b/execroot/tensorflow && \
  exec env - \
    PYTHON_BIN_PATH=/usr/bin/python3 \
    TF_NEED_CUDA=0 \
    TF_NEED_OPENCL=0 \
  external/androidndk/ndk/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc -o bazel-out/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9-v7a-gnu-libstdcpp-py3-opt/bin/myproject bazel-out/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9-v7a-gnu-libstdcpp-py3-opt/bin/_objs/myproject/myproject.o bazel-out/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9-v7a-gnu-libstdcpp-py3-opt/bin/libmymodel.a -Wl,-whole-archive bazel-out/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9-v7a-gnu-libstdcpp-py3-opt/bin/tensorflow/compiler/tf2xla/kernels/libgather_op_kernel_float_int32.lo -Wl,-no-whole-archive -Wl,-whole-archive bazel-out/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9-v7a-gnu-libstdcpp-py3-opt/bin/tensorflow/compiler/tf2xla/kernels/libgather_op_kernel_float_int64.lo -Wl,-no-whole-archive -Wl,-whole-archive bazel-out/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9-v7a-gnu-libstdcpp-py3-opt/bin/tensorflow/core/kernels/libgather_functor.lo -Wl,-no-whole-archive -Wl,-whole-archive bazel-out/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9-v7a-gnu-libstdcpp-py3-opt/bin/tensorflow/compiler/tf2xla/kernels/libindex_ops_kernel_argmax_float_1d.lo -Wl,-no-whole-archive -Wl,-whole-archive bazel-out/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9-v7a-gnu-libstdcpp-py3-opt/bin/tensorflow/compiler/tf2xla/kernels/libindex_ops_kernel_argmax_float_2d.lo -Wl,-no-whole-archive bazel-out/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9-v7a-gnu-libstdcpp-py3-opt/bin/tensorflow/compiler/aot/libruntime.a bazel-out/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9-v7a-gnu-libstdcpp-py3-opt/bin/tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/cpu/libruntime_conv2d.a bazel-out/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9-v7a-gnu-libstdcpp-py3-opt/bin/tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/cpu/libruntime_matmul.a bazel-out/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9-v7a-gnu-libstdcpp-py3-opt/bin/tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/cpu/libruntime_single_threaded_conv2d.a bazel-out/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9-v7a-gnu-libstdcpp-py3-opt/bin/tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/cpu/libruntime_single_threaded_matmul.a bazel-out/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9-v7a-gnu-libstdcpp-py3-opt/bin/tensorflow/compiler/xla/libexecutable_run_options.a external/androidndk/ndk/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/libs/armeabi-v7a/libgnustl_static.a external/androidndk/ndk/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/libs/armeabi-v7a/libsupc++.a -llog -lm -Wl,--export-dynamic -static-libgcc -no-canonical-prefixes '-march=armv7-a' -Wl,--fix-cortex-a8 '--sysroot=external/androidndk/ndk/platforms/android-14/arch-arm'): com.google.devtools.build.lib.shell.BadExitStatusException: Process exited with status 1.
bazel-out/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9-v7a-gnu-libstdcpp-py3-opt/bin/mymodel.a(mymodel.o):__compute_module:function ____mymodel: error: undefined reference to '__multi3'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Target //:myproject failed to build
INFO: Elapsed time: 1244.464s, Critical Path: 925.30s
```